# List folder files and in_array wrong datatype for second argument error

Tags: php

I am trying to list files in one folder and check file extensions (for only show file if in array) But I am getting "Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in.." error message. How can I fix this problem?

```
$ext_white = array("css", "jpg", "png", "mp3", "wav", "wma", "mid", "avi", "mp4", "mpg", "wmv", "flv", "swf", "zip", "rar", "ttf", "txt", "pdf", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "pps", "ppt", "pptx", "odt", "ods", "odp");

if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
//count($ext_white) > 0
if (!is_dir($file) && $file!= "." && $file!= "..") {
$ext = file_ext($file);
if (in_array($ext,$ext_white,TRUE)) {
echo "file : $file (".file_ext($file).")\n<br>";
}
}
}
closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: On what line error happens, are you sure this happens in this piece of code?

Comment: I did try now only this code in a test php file and working good. I am sorry I guess problem coming in function usage.